# Is any finite subset of $S^2$ satisfying the following properties, the vertex set of a regular convex polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra

Let $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the standard unit sphere.

Let $A \subset S^2$ be a finite set satisfying each of the following properties:

> 1. For each $a,a' \in A$ there exists a rotation $R$ (the action of a 3x3 orthogonal matrix) such that $R(A) = A$ and $R(a) = a'$.
> 2. The set $A$ is not contained in any one plane. (Such a plane need not pass through the origin.)

My question is, in the above situation, is $A$ necessarily the set of vertices of some regular convex polyhedron (embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$)?

Comment: Note: thanks to a comment on my earlier question for pointing out the issues that arise if condition 2 above is not applied

Comment: The convex hull of such a set is an _isogonal_ polyhedron. This needn't be regular or even uniform; for example, it could be a square prism ($a\times a\times b$ where $a\neq b$).

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Archimedean solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid) for which

> A global isometry of the entire solid takes one vertex to the other
> while laying the solid directly on its initial position.

[image]

There may be other examples.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!